# Ember-data Relationships like polymorphic , async , inverse , embedded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can anyone explain about ember-data model relationships like polymorphic , async , embedded, inverse ? And when to use all these relationships ?
 I searched a lot and i found some explanations but i didn't understand those properties . It helps me to design my models . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding see this post
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-relationships-like-polymorphic-async-inverse-embedded/5029